# PYTHON: IF Statements for DICT

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a `dict` which contains data from my `csv` file:

```
Standard rules1: Weight <= 1200 |
                 Height <= 220 |
                 Width  <= 100 |
                 Length <= 120

Standard rules2: Weight <= 750 |
                 Height <= 120 |
                 Width  <= 100 |
                 Length <= 120 |
```

my dict:

```
pwData = {'Weight':row[0], 'Length':row[3], 'Width':row[4], 'Height':row[4], 'Rule' : ''}
```

what i want is:

```
if pwData['Weight'] <= '750' and pwData['Height'] <= '160':
    pwData['Rule'] = '1'
elif pwData['Weigt'] <= '750' and pwData['Height'] <= '120':
    pwData['Rule'] <= '2'
```

What i get in the firs if statement:
Rule `2` but i need to get the rule `1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder your if statements.

```
if pwData['Weight'] <= '750' and pwData['Height'] <= '120':
    pwData['Rule'] = '2'
elif pwData['Weight'] <= '1200' and pwData['Height'] <= '220':
    pwData['Rule'] <= '1'
```

Comment: thank you for helping me... if i run this code it just show me the numbers which are exactly 750 not the the range between 0 and 750.

Comment: The code just assigns the appropriate value according to the "Rule". If you want to do something else, you have to write more code.